# Pages: can I change the document font size but retain the italics?

Tags: applescript, pages, font

I've got a 500 page Pages ('09 v4.3 on OS X 10.12.6) document where all text is 14 point; I want to change to 12. The problem is that there are blocks of italic text throughout. Using `Select all` to change to 12 point of course changes all the italic text to normal. How can change the document font size to 12 but retain the italics? Could Applescript parse the document and change the font size and retain the italics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you're doing to affect the italics. Changing one aspect should not change any other.

Select all text. Multi-style selections will show as Multiple in the style box. In the Text tab click the size button… all else is retained except the font size.

Window shrunk to only show relevant area…

[image]

If your text already has multiple font sizes, meaning the point size box is greyed out, then use  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   and  <kbd>+</kbd>  or  <kbd>-</kbd>  which will change all by one point at a time, maintaining relative sizes.
If you use that box in this instance, all type will be set to the **same** font size, breaking the relationship.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Not enough coffee when I asked that question....